# Install updated APK automatically

Tags: android

I want to install the update automatically as my APK is not on the Play store. So I tried the following:

I followed all the steps given in

```
http://www.wepstech.com/download-and-install-app-programmatically/
```

Below is the Async Task: (URL given is correct)

```
URL url = new URL(arg0[0]);
                HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                c.setRequestMethod("GET");
                c.setDoOutput(true);
                c.connect();
                int lenghtOfFile = c.getContentLength();

                String PATH = Objects.requireNonNull(mContext.getExternalFilesDir(null)).getAbsolutePath();
                File file = new File(PATH);
                boolean isCreate = file.mkdirs();
                File outputFile = new File(file, "my_apk.apk");
                if (outputFile.exists()) {
                    boolean isDelete = outputFile.delete();
                }
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

                InputStream is = c.getInputStream();

                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int len1;
                long total = 0;
                while ((len1 = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    total += len1;
                    fos.write(buffer, 0, len1);
                    publishProgress((int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile));
                }
                fos.close();
                is.close();
                if (mPDialog != null)
                    mPDialog.dismiss()
```

;

I have an API checking the version and if the version is old I have given a button to download and install, So when I do that the apk is getting downloaded only (but not a full-size file) I see only 189bytes. The Async just closes thinking the file has downloaded it starts to install and when it does it gives "There was a problem parsing the package".

It is because the APK file not downloaded fully.

I am not sure why the file is not getting downloaded fully. It is an 8MB file. And I am running Android 11.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the lib fetch, it's a best file downloader library for android

https://github.com/tonyofrancis/Fetch

Comment: I tried to fetch.  The download is not happening..  I get java.io.IOException: file_allocation_error:(